# Название класса со знаком подчеркивания "_" на конце

Tags: java, классы, чистый-код

Сейчас разбираюсь в чужом коде и столкнулся со странными вещами. Есть два вида классов в проекте одни с нормальным названием, другие с знаком подчерчикания на конце SomeClass и SomeClass_. Причем классы внутри действительно разные.

Классы со знаком подчеркивания изначально лежали не в проекте, но по package, я понял где они должны были бы лежать, и добавил их туда. IDEA сразу начала ругаться, на то, что дублирование классов.

Соответственно вопрос, разве SomeClass и SomeClass_ воспринимается как классы с одним и тем же названием или это загоны IDEA или что это вообще?

---

Оказывается.... Если есть код следующего типа. (Это я так понимаю называется бином)

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable{

    @Id
    protected int id;

    public Test() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

То  при компиляции мавеном в папке target/classes/... помимо скомпилированных классов с нормальным именем типа Test.class генерируются еще и Test_.class

Почему так, сейчас разбираюсь

Comment: Возможно просто кто-то так сохранил класс перед его изменением и он в проекте сейчас не нужен. Так можно только гадать

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но SomeClass_ и SomeClass реально используется далее в проекте и используются по разному

Comment: Возможно `SomeClass_` сгенерирован какой-то аннотацией

Comment: Надо анализировать, без кода вам вряд ли кто-то поможет.

Comment: Да не, не в том вопрос. Классы то я вижу и те и другие, они в наличии есть. Вопрос в том, почему, когда я размещаю в одной папке разные классы (SomeClass и SomeClass_) идеа ругается на то, что они одинаковые.

Comment: Только что пробовал создать классы, идея их видит как разные, так что причина точно не в Idea

Comment: Прикольно. Создал именно с названием SomeClass SomeClass_ и получилось создать. А те что в проекте, ругаются на дублирование. Код я конечно целиком сюда не залью. Что это может быть, хотя бы направление.

Comment: Это явление так и останется для Вас загадкой, потому что Вы не хотите ни код показать, ни точное сообщение об ошибке привести. А предпочитаете называть это "IDEA ругается".

Comment: завтра попробую оставить здесь код, который будет повторять эту ошибку. Ну или в ближайшее время.

Comment: @Dmitrii, мне тоже стало интересно) поделитесь кодом)

Comment: @Ruslan Gorbunov Добавил ответ, если кому то была интересна тема.

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно, речь идет о создание метамодели для класса в JPA 2

В API-интерфейсе критериев JPA метамодель создается с именем класса сущности и суффикса _.

Т.е. сущность — ClassNameEntity и метамодель — ClassNameEntity_ .

https://javastudy.ru/spring-data-jpa/generate-metamodel/